# How to instanciate class which need Dependancy Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I m using Angular 6.1.1 and I've a class model which need an injected service variable.
Is there any way to instanciate my class without providing any DI ?

Maybe, i'm doing that in the wrong way, how to well used angular with this kind of use case.

Thanks in advance

The goal is to achieve this works with well injectedService in the class

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class AuthenticationService {        
      public User : User = new User();    
      constructor() { }
    }

    export class Item {
        public UserCreator: User;
        // Other properties
        constructor(private authenticationService : AuthenticationService) {        
            this.UserCreator = this.authenticationService.User;
       }
   }

    export class ExampleComponent {
        constructor() {
            const newItem : Item = new Item();
        //Doesn't compiled because need authenticationService argument
        //Is there any way to ask Angular to instanciate this class with auto resolving the injection of the authenticationService ?
       }
   }
```

Comment: If it's an item that you will create, why does it have @Injectable ? it should be on service ?

Comment: to make the injection works for the example of course, i want to remove it

Comment: `{providedIn: 'root' }` means it is provided in the root module, making it a singleton. Why would you create a new instance of that service ?

Comment: I recreate my example to be more comprehensible

Comment: create a stackblitz to show us what you want to do

Comment: I just want ton instanciate my class without providing the authenticationService because of Angular got it DI